# Selecting content with no element wrapped around

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In below code, I want to hide the **"Lorem Ipsum is a dummy content"** by showing the other elements inside the parent container, either by using jquery, javascript or CSS? Solution much appreciated.

```
 <div class="someWrapper">
     Lorem Ipsum is a dummy content
      <div class="anotherContainer">
          <p>Text goes here</p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hide it by showing the other elements," do you mean cover it up?

Comment: Do the contents of `anotherContainer` need to be transferred to `.someWrapper` or hide the contents of `.someWrapper` with `.anotherContainer`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do that you need to target the `textNode` of the `.someWrapper` element and remove them from the DOM. To do that you can use `filter()` and `remove()`. Try this:

```js
$('.someWrapper').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE; // 3
}).remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someWrapper">
  Lorem Ipsum is a dummy content
  <div class="anotherContainer">
    <p>Text goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Rory it worked fine for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a one liner, either with plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('someWrapper')[0].firstChild.remove();
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/fd0h2moy/)**

or jQuery:

```
$($('.someWrapper').get(0).firstChild).remove();
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q5jxuLvL/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can select inner content, empty outer element and append inner ounce again:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $outer = $('.someWrapper');
  $inner = $('.anotherContainer');
  $outer.empty();
  $outer.html($inner);
});
```

here is fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/woo3cgwx/

Comment: Your solution would work only in this particular case, i.e. it would not work if in `anotherContainer`, before `<p>Text goes here</p>` there were another text node without a wrapper.

Comment: @AlessioCantarella You are right. I want to show the most intuitive and easy way to do it.